# dynamics ax 2009 x++: UNION QueryBuildDataSource - remove record

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a union between two of the same tables (LedgerJournalTable):

```
LedgerJournalTable_ds.query().queryType( UnionType::Union );

qbdsLedger1 = LedgerJournalTable_ds
.query()
.DataSourceTable(tablenum(LedgerJournalTable) );

qbdsLedger2 = LedgerJournalTable_ds
.query()
.addDataSource( tablenum(LedgerJournalTable), "L2" );
```

The union works correctly, but when I remove a record on the form I receive the following error message:

> You can not delete a record from the LedgerJournalTable
>   table. Deletion is not supported for the relationship.

Remove from other place where table is not unioned is available without any errors.

sorry for my bad English :c

Comment: Have you tried `UnionType::UnionAll`? I think `UnionType::Union` automatically removes duplicates so that might be why you can't delete?

Comment: i need to use UnionType:Union, i find some way, but i dont think is a good result for that. In delete methods on datasource, before super(), i use
select firstonly forupdate LedgerJournalTable where LedgerJournalTable.RecId == id;

Comment: this work, but it is correctly with ax standards?

Comment: Well it depends on what you're doing. Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc605991.aspx to see more information about it. `UnionAll` includes duplicates where `Union` eliminates them. There doesn't appear to be any documentation around WHY you can't delete with a `Union` but I suspect it's because duplicate records are omitted?

Comment: i not want any duplicate, 
maybe UnionAll can allow for delete, but i can't switch into this type without any run execute query, and after that the selected record is missing

Comment: Wow, i tried to tidy this post up and my edits were rejected. No wonder the axapta community in SO is so bad.